# Ejecutar evento de un Formulario desde otro formulario

Tags: c#

Tengo un evento en un formulario principal `Form1` con el nombre `Gestion`. Lo que necesito es que al realizar un click en el `boton1` de mi `Form2` se ejecute ese evento y que el `Form2` se cierre.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, muestra que intentaste hasta ahora.

Answer (score 4):

No necesitas invocar un evento el el `form padre` sino invocar una funcion que expongas.

En el articulo explico como conectas los forms para tener la instancia del `form padre`  Form1 desde el `form hijo` Form2

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

La idea es que definas una interfaz como ser

```
interface IForm{
   void Metodo1();
}
```

Entonces haces que el form implemente la interface

```
public class Form1 : Form, IForm{

    //codigo del form

    public void Metodo1(){
      //codigo
    }

    private void abrirform2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
       frm2.Show();      
    }
}
```

Cuando invocas el form pasa la instancia en el constructor

El acceso a los datos, o realizar acciones del forma principal lo realizas mediante los metodos o propiedades que definas en la interface.

En el `Form2` usarias

```
public class Form2:Form {

  private IForm _form;

  public Form2(IForm form){ //este es el constructor
       _form = form;
  }

  public void button1_Click(...){
       _form.Metodo1();
       this.Close()
  }
}
```

Todo esto lo explico mejor en el artículo que propuse al principio.